# Need to show / hide a div on clicking on a link

Tags: show-hide

I'd like to do something like this fiddle only this works on buttons instead of links:

http://jsfiddle.net/qNhZj/

I need it to work on links and also i have an intro div which gets hidden after clicking on one of the links.

Can anyone help me out please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to declare link instead of input.
In the class list, add the `id` of the `div` you want to show.

```
Click a button to make it visible:

<div id="intro-tekst">Intro text here !</div>
<div class="boxes" id="coke">Coke is awesome!</div>
<div class="boxes" id="bubble-tea">Bubble tea is da bomb!</div>
<div class="boxes" id="milk">Milk is healthy!</div>
<br />
<p>
    I change my mind:
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link coke">Coke</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link bubble-tea">Bubble Tea</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link milk">Milk</a></li>
    </ul>
</p>
```

And bind it like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var option = url.match(/option=(.*)/);
    if (option !== null) {
        $(".link ." . option[1]).trigger('click');
    }

    $(".link").bind('click', function () {
        $('#intro-tekst').hide();
        $('.boxes').hide();
        $('.link').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).removeClass('link');
        $('#' + $(this).prop('class')).show();
        $(this).addClass('link selected');       
    });   
});
```

JsFiddle code here :   http://jsfiddle.net/Pq5Cv/8/

Comment: Hi Palmplam, this is what I asked for, but my problem now is that it shows #one into the URL. (i work in a cms and don't want any #links :s )

Any idea i can change this so i don't see any url change?
Buttons would be oke also, but when I add a div over this button it gets hidden.

So thats why i wanted to go for links.

Comment: Somehow i have a js conflict or something.

Is there any way to use your script and do the same as I have done? 
So with a "intro".

Comment: @MarcHoogstrate I edit my answer with improved code. In fact, you use : `option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1]` directly and if `option` is `null`, you have an error.

Comment: Thanks again ! this one works indeed.

I did manage some ugly way to do it with the buttons version and used some inline styling (display:block / hidden) but I like this one much better.

It's so much easier when knowing js :(